# Remove the Close title attribute from Google Maps custom marker's infowindow

Tags: jquery, google-maps

I'm trying to figure out how to remove the word "Close" in the top-right corner of this image:

[image]

I've found that I can run this jQuery command and it works, but only if I run the command after the window is already open:

```
            jQuery(".gm-ui-hover-effect").attr('title', '');
```

This issue is that if I put it in the click listener for the info Window it doesn't seem to work:

```
    function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infowindow, html) {
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.setContent(html);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
            jQuery(".gm-ui-hover-effect").attr('title', '');
        });
    }
```

I'm open to hiding it with CSS/JS/whatever, but after searching for 2 days I cannot find a solution for this (and for some reason my Chrome isn't unformatting the minified code, so tracing have proven very difficult, but that's another problem).

Anyone have any ideas on how to hide this?

Comment: Try adding a setTimeout in case `open()` is asynchronous. Also assuming you have the correct class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`domready`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/info-window#InfoWindow.domready) event on the [InfoWindow](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/info-window#InfoWindow) to run the function to remove the title.

From [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/info-window#InfoWindow.domready):

> **domready** 
>  
>   function()
>   Arguments:  None
>   This event is fired when the  containing the InfoWindow's content is attached to the DOM. **You may wish to monitor this event if you are building out your info window content dynamically**.

```
function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infowindow, html) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.setContent(html);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
        google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'domready', function() {
          jQuery(".gm-ui-hover-effect").attr('title', '');
        });
    });
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/n6fa98xj/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initMap() {
  var uluru = {
    lat: -25.363,
    lng: 131.044
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: uluru
  });

  var contentString = '<div id="content">' +
    '<div id="siteNotice">' +
    '</div>' +
    '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Uluru</h1>' +
    '<div id="bodyContent">' +
    '<p>some content</p>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>';

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: contentString
  });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: uluru,
    map: map,
    title: 'Uluru (Ayers Rock)'
  });
  marker.addListener('click', function() {
    console.log("open infowindow");
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
    google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'domready', function() {
      console.log("remove title")
      jQuery(".gm-ui-hover-effect").attr('title', '');
    });
  });
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap"></script>
```